# RAISEERROR Date and Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have long running sql statement inside TRY...CATCH.

```
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),@ErrSevirity = Error_Sevirity()
    RAISEERROR(@ErrorMsg , @ErrSevirity , 1)     
    --do rollback
END CATCH
```

I know what time The stored procedure failed, How do I get the the error message? sysmessages doesn't have date time field,is there any way I can join it to other table to get Error Date and Time?

```
select * from master.dbo.sysmessages
```

Comment: What's wrong with `DECLARE @ErrorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()`?

Comment: It failed last night,How do I get that message?

Comment: If it failed last night then you should have some sort of code in place to log the error details in some sort of log table. If the error occured and you have captured that information than it is somewhat lost. Unless you go into your Error Logs and find required information there, read here to learn more about [`SQL Server Error Log`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187109(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using RAISERROR() Function inside your Catch block doesnt make much sense, This is something you would use in a `TRY BLock` to get into `Catch Block`.

Once you are (Your Control) is in Catch block , you have all the error functions there to get a detailed information about your error. Simply Select them functions.

Raiserror function is used in try block. And once you have raised an error in try block, ERROR_MESSAGE() will be populated with your custom error message.

See below:

```
BEGIN TRY
       -- Pre validation 
         IF (Some COndition)
         BEGIN
             RAISERROR('Your Customer Error message', 16,1) 
         END
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

   /* Your Code here  */

COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
 IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  END

   -- Do your Error logging 
   SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()  AS ErrorMessage
         ,ERROR_LINE()     AS ErrorLine 
         ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity 
         ,GETDATE()        AS Error_DateTime

END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to track SP Execution step timing:

```
IF @diagbit = 1
BEGIN
SET @timestamp = 'Main Table Created - '+CAST(CAST(GETDATE() as TIME) as VARCHAR(20))
RAISERROR (@timestamp, 0,1) WITH NOWAIT
END
```

So for you it would be:

```
@ErrorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE() + CAST(CAST(GETDATE() as TIME) as VARCHAR(20)) ,@ErrSevirity = Error_Sevirity()
```

Or something similar.